# How to add a custom value to current URL

Tags: php, url-rewriting, elgg

i use a CMS (elgg : http://www.elgg.org ) working with view, equivalent to theme/template. To change the theme i have to put inside URL the term ?view=mytheme, like :

http://www.mydomain.com/index.php?view=mytheme

If i don't add ?view=mytheme, elgg choose the view by default

So, i need help, for specific users, i want to redirect us to a custom view, and can't see the default view.

I make this in my header :

```
<?php 

  if ((string) $_SESSION['user']->type === '2') {
    // ???
  } else {
    echo 'do nothing';
  }
```

I don't know how to take the current url, and simple add ?view=mytheme at the end ?

When a user have the type '2', and see the the url http://www.mydomain.com/index.php
it have to be forward to > http://www.mydomain.com/index.php?view=mytheme

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of CMS is this? Does it have special features for redirection?

Comment: It's elgg.  I believe this is a social networking CMS.  I don't know about any specific redirection built in, as my only experience with it is from about four years ago.

Comment: Sorry, i edit my message, forgoit to precise it's ELGG (1.7.14), and don't know if it have a special features for redirection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is kinda dirty, but you could:

```
// Stole this from here: http://webcheatsheet.com/php/get_current_page_url.php
function curPageURL() {
    $pageURL = 'http';
    if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
    $pageURL .= "://";
    if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
        $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    } else {
        $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    }
    return $pageURL;
}

$useCustomView = ((string)$_SESSION['user']->type) === '2';
$usingCustomView = isset($_GET["view"]);
// Redirect to custom view if user type is 2 and view is not already set
if ($useCustomView && !$usingCustomView) {
        $newurl = curPageURL() . '?view=mytheme';
        header("Location: $newurl");
}
```

This is the most basic example I can think of to accomplish what you're asking. This won't quite do the job if you want the URL to support longer query strings so it needs some work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Codemonkey,
There is something in :
if ((string) $_SESSION['user']->type === '2' &&
    !isset($_GET["view"]) {
        $newurl = curPageURL() . '?view=mytheme';
        header("Location: $newurl");
}

That elgg don't seems to like ...

I write this :
if ({"$_SESSION['user']->type"} === '2') {
        $newurl = curPageURL() . '?view=mytheme';
        header("Location: $newurl");
}

and it's work, but it had for each request ?view=mytheme ... it's seems to be inside !isset ...

Comment: Try the updated, it's more clean. Neither `isset` nor `$_GET` has anything to do with elgg, so that's not the issue.

Comment: You're no a monkey, but a genious ;)
Thanks Codemonkey